# Is it correct to say "he lay on the bed rolling himself up because of cold"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Look at the above picture, is it correct to say "**he lay on the bed rolling himself up because of cold**"?

Or **Do we have a common word to express that lying position?**

Comment: I would use 'he curled himself up because he was cold.' As a side note, if he's cold, whys he not wearing pants or socks???

Answer (score 2):

It's called "fetal position", something like the disposition of an infant (fetus) in the womb. He isn't "rolling himself up" - that's a process. You need a word for a state - he is curled up.

Comment: What about "he lied curled up"? is it idiomatic?

Comment: It would be "...he lay, curled up..."